# Does dune support glob patterns for libraries?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune, dune

#### Background

I'm trying to expose two `dune` libraries from the same directory - one for some interfaces, and the other for their implementations.

For example, let's say I have the following sources:

###### **`foo_api.ml`**

```ml
module type Foo = sig
  val foo: string
end
```

###### **`foo.ml`**

```ml
module FooImpl: Foo =
  let foo = "foo"
end
```

In my `dune` file, I want to expose these as separate libraries - an API and an implementation. I'd really like to be able to use globs here to specify the modules, as I'm planning on using this pattern for other modules, eg. `Bar.ml` and `Bar_api.ml`.

#### Question

Does `dune` support some way of globbing (or regex'ing) for modules?

```
(library
 (name foo_lib_api)
 (modules (glob_files "./*_api.ml")))

(library
 (name foo_lib_implementation)
 (modules (:standard \ (glob_files "./*_api.ml"))))
```

The above syntax does not work, and I haven't found anything that does work. Perhaps I'm trying to use `dune` like I would use `bazel`, which would let me use [`glob`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/functions#glob) or [`filegroup`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#filegroup).

Answer (score 1):

Dune does not support glob patterns in the modules stanza.

A more idiomatic alternative would be to have one directory, which has the advantages of allowing to decouple the module and library names.

Comment: Interesting - I suppose that would mean creating a `foo/` directory, with `foo/api/dune` for the API, and `foo/dune` or `foo/implementation/dune` for the implementation. Yes, I suppose that 's one way to do it, and it's fairly clean.

Good idea!